# iOS UITableView override autolayout constraints programatically after setTableHeaderView

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints, autolayout

Okey so this is my dilemma atm.

I have a storyboard with a UITableView (tableView) and UIView (viewForTableHeader) that contains several other objects like a UIImag a label and such.

Programatically I set the UIView to be the header of the UITableView by doing:

```
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.viewForTableHeader];
```

This works perfectly when Not using the autolayout.

But with autolayout the app crashes and leaves me with:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

So in viewDidLoad I have tried to set the constraints of the `viewForTableHeader` to be:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewForTableHeader attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:0 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewForTableHeader attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:0 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

and I also tried:

```
- (void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    [super layoutSublayersOfLayer:self.tableView.layer];
```

and did same thing trying to set the constraints here

```
}
```

Is it maby better to have the `viewForTableHeader` in a nib file?
I do am a bit noobish at this so realy any help or pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have both (the tableView and the headerView) in IB, you can **drag** the viewForTableHeader to (over) the tableView and set it as table header.

This will make the headerView appear **below** the tableView in the **views hierarchy**.

If you do this you'll be able to remove/add this view to the table later during run time with no auto layout errors or extra constraints.

```
  [self.viewForTableHeader removeFromSuperview];
```

and later

```
  [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.viewForTableHeader];
```

Comment: oh that sounded all so easy :)
So I did as you told and draged the viewForTableHeader over the tableView and yes, thats all I had to do.
*sigh*
I realy overworked my ass of on this one.
So thanks a lot Mariam N!